# Separated elements in Vec by comma

Tags: rust

I have a `Vec` of `UUID`'s. I want to add comma's **between** the `UUID`'s and put the result in between two `&str` to create a `String`. This is what I have now:

```
pub fn select_ids(ids: Vec<Uuid>) -> String {
    let x: String = ids.into_iter().map(|id| {
        id.to_string() + ","
    }).collect();

    "(".to_owned() + &x + ")"
}
```

This is my test:

```
#[test]
fn t() {
    let uuid = Uuid::from_str("123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000").unwrap();
    let x = select_ids(vec!(uuid, uuid.clone()));

    assert_eq!(x, "(123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000,123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000)");
}
```

It fails with the following:

```
Expected :(123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000,123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000)
Actual   :(123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000,123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000,)
```

Ofcourse I can cut off the last character, but that will fail if the list contains only 1 id. I am wondering if there is a build in option, like Java has (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/java-8-streams-collectors-joining-method-with-examples/).

Comment: @justinas Just tried it, the join method isn't available on a Vec with UUID's properly :(

Comment: Well, you already `map()` them to strings, so I figured it would not be a problem to turn `Vec<Uuid>` to a `Vec<String>` or similar. Do you need help with that?

Comment: @justinas this means they would have to `collect` into a temporary vector. @J. Doe the duplicate question has several answers. The `itertools` one would be the one to use here.

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your question](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=54bc52936ac3b1eaa6ae568ea75a63f6)

Comment: @justinas No you were right, it is a duplicate and I just needed to create String Vec to make it work, thanks :)

Comment: @mcarton yes correct, my bad!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`join`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.8.2/itertools/fn.join.html) method from the [`itertools`](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) crate:

```
use itertools::join;
pub use uuid::Uuid;

pub fn select_ids(ids: Vec<Uuid>) -> String {
    "(".to_owned() + &join (ids, ",") + ")"
}

#[test]
fn t() {
    use std::str::FromStr;
    let uuid = Uuid::from_str("123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000").unwrap();
    let x = select_ids(vec!(uuid, uuid.clone()));

    assert_eq!(x, "(123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000,123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426655440000)");
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=254ae9553244cb36ef42fc41e5f6f87d)